# CityEngine Rule for Area

Tags: area, parcel, cityengine

I have been successful at creating rules for already established footprints in CityEngine.  However, I recently received a project to create a proposed commercial and residential development.  I have all the known buildings extruded but for the new buildings I only have empty parcels.  Creating a rule to extrude based on floors, shape, height, and setback is not the issue and all are based on a zone, which I have a rule file for already.   What I can't figure out is how to create the building size based on Sq Feet, which is the only numbers given to me.

Is there a rule for Sq Feet/meters instead of width and length?

Also how can I put a random number of buildings on a parcel using a density based on Acreage?

For example 16-24 units per acre.  The acreage is included in the parcel features in CityEngine.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour and edit your question to include additional information. What additional information do you have provided (if you only have square footage, it seems impossible to create a building shape without having dimensions of the footprint/how many stories, etc)? What have you already tried and what didnt' work?

Answer (score 1):

As @MaryBeth already pointed out there are infinite possibilities to create a rectangle given the area of the rectangle. Therefore you can't just provide that information to an operation and it'll do what you want.

One option you have is to use `innerRectangle` to create some sort of an optimal rectangle in your parcel. Using `scope.sx` and `scope.sy` you could then compute the area of this rectangle (in meters if you don't convert).
Now you know how much area less area your building should have. From that you can compute the setback from the large rectangle you need. Feed this number into the operation `setback` and you'll have a shape that has the requested area.